# Best bi-amping combo for metal?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

been thinking about putting a Mesa triple rec through the bottom 4x12 for low end rhythms and a 6505+ through the top for high end gain lead via an effects processor. What do you guys think? What are your favourite combinations, both actual and one you want?

Comment: This is kind of an "opinion" question. I think you should try it and see if it does what you want.